# How to show a message or warning to user when they extract zip file on Windows?

Tags: windows, zip

Our group needs to distribute an update to a software package we make. There have been changes in this revision that affect users who installed a previous version; some of the file names have changed, and we want to alert users to the fact that if they unzip over their old copy, they will be left with files that are no longer relevant.  We *thought* we could do this using the comment feature available in the zip format, and indeed, it does work when people unzip the file on Linux or double-click the file on Windows.  However, if they right-click on the file in Windows and use the "Extract" option, they are *not* shown the comment text.

Is there a way around this?  More generally, is there a way to make a zip file display a comment or dialog, or some other means of providing users information at the time they unzip the archive?

Comment: There is nothing in the ZIP file format that requires the client to display a message before extracting. You could password-protect your ZIP file with the password "Do not unzip over an old copy of the program. Unzip into a new directory instead."

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, you're right about the zip format. I was hoping that nevertheless there might be a common approach people use, or a clever trick, or something...